# Where to attach ball hitch on 1989 10ft former U-Haul truck?

Tags: truck, towing

I have a 1989 Toyota 10 ft box truck that was a U-haul in a former life.  I would like to attach a 2 inch ball hitch to the rear.  Problem is, this is a low step loading configuration where there seems to be no practical and safe way to attach the ball receiver.

[image: rear of box truck]

So, I was wondering if it was possible to attach the ball hitch directly to the lip that is level with the floor of the truck.  Any lower and it would be too low for most towing applications.  I don't think a weld would hold as good as bolt and nut after drilling through.  The steel seems to be thicker there as well.

[image: top view of lip]

[image]

Would this be possible and safe?  The ball would get it the way and possibly cause injury during regular loading and unloading.  I am sure I am not the first to want this.  I asked U-haul a month ago and they still haven't gotten back to me.

Comment: the ball hitch needs to be connected to the chassis - the step, unless it is a structural member, will not be strong enough. If you can't recognize a suitable member then go to a garage / or trailer place and get them to do it - for your safety AND everyone else's...

Answer (score 3):

The ball hitch needs to be properly connected to the chassis - the step, unless it is a structural member, will not be strong enough. If you can't recognize a suitable member then go to a garage / or trailer place and get them to identify it or do the work - for your safety AND everyone else's..